How to find the Nth match values & automatically update for all the rows?
I'm trying to find the date range that match certain condition and want it to automatically update for all the recurring rows. I've a list of dates (in random order) in Column A and would like to assign the corresponding date range to Column B. The data is in Column C (start date), Column D (end date) and Column E (combined date range).
The data & calculations are in the sheet below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WfBCO1wSBwHxMTpM8I42E3dQjiIg8sNjBdngNlOPw_w/edit?usp=sharing
List of Dates (first 10 rows for reference) // Dates (Column A), Weekly Range (Column B)



Dates
Weekly Range




2024-06-30



2024-06-30



2024-07-01



2024-07-03



2024-07-04



2024-07-05



2024-07-06



2024-07-07



2024-07-08



2024-07-09




Data (first 3 rows for reference) // Start date (Column C), End date (Column D), Weekly Range (Column E).



Start Date
End Date
Weekly Range




2024-06-30
2024-07-06
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-07
2024-07-13
2024/07/07 - 2024/07/13


2024-07-14
2024-07-20
2024/07/14 - 2024/07/20



I've tried a few formulas using INDEX, MATCH, VLOOKUP but does not seem to work. I just want the date range from Column E to be assigned to Column B based on the respective dates in Column A. Example result in Column O.
Expected result: // Dates (Column N), Weekly Range (Column O).



Dates
Weekly Range




2024-06-30
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-01
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-02
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-03
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-04
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-05
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-06
2024/06/30 - 2024/07/06


2024-07-07
2024/07/07 - 2024/07/13


2024-07-08
2024/07/07 - 2024/07/13


2024-07-09
2024/07/07 - 2024/07/13



Could anyone help to highlight which part I'm missing?  Thank you so much for your assistance.

From the very beginning of the [tag:google-sheets-formula] tag: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors., too.  Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,sequence(max(A:A)-min(A:A)+7,1,min(A:A)-6),
 map(A3:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(Δ,filter(Σ,weeknum(Σ)=weeknum(Λ)),text(min(Δ),"e/mm/dd")&" - "&text(max(Δ),"e/mm/dd"))))))



Hi @rockinfreakshow Thank you so much! Work perfectly =) Let me try to understand the formula.  Certain function like lambda, let, map are quite new for me.. =)

Here's other approach that finds the week range by substracting the weekday's number:
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",
TEXT(each-WEEKDAY(each)+1,"YYYY/MM/DD")&" - "&TEXT(each-WEEKDAY(each)+7,"YYYY/MM/DD"))))



Hi Martin, thank you so much! This formula worked as well. Can I know more about the 'each' parameter? Would use useful to apply for any similar cases. Any reference much appreciate.. Thanks

Here's another solution using ARRAYFORMULA and CEILING functions.
={"Weekly Range";ARRAYFORMULA(text(CEILING(tocol(A2:A,1)-7,7)+1,"yyyy/MM/dd")&" - "&text(ceiling(tocol(A2:A,1),7),"yyyy/MM/dd"))}


Hi @Kreeszh Thank you very much! It works as well.  Much simpler. Let me explore the "tocol" function.
